# What is the earliest point of access to the DOM window object during a page load in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to inject JavaScript into Android WebView at the earliest possible opportunity during a page load, ideally when the DOM window object is created. How can I achieve this?

WebViewClient.onPageStarted looked like what I was looking for. But during page transitions, the window still contains the window object of the previous page meaning the window object for the new page is yet to be created.

Note 1: The URL I am loading is a third party URL meaning I have no control over its content.

Note 2: I am looking for the equivalent of DOMWindowCreated in Mozilla if you are aware of it.